# JPA 2.1 Stored Procedure getOutputParameterValue() returns incorrect Data Type

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, ejb-3.1, jpa-2.1

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `pct_getNextMenuId` (IN venueId INT UNSIGNED, OUT menuId TINYINT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
    UPDATE Venues SET lastSeqIdMenus = LAST_INSERT_ID(lastSeqIdMenus + 1) WHERE  id=venueId LIMIT 1;
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO menuId;
END
```

Which I've annotated in my EJB Entity like so:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries( {
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name="getNextMenuId", procedureName="pct_getNextMenuId", parameters={
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="venueId", type=Long.class, mode=ParameterMode.IN),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="menuId", type=Short.class, mode=ParameterMode.OUT)}
    )
})
```

And now trying to use it in my Java code:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getNextMenuId");
query.setParameter("venueId", venueId);
query.execute();
Short menuId = (Short) query.getOutputParameterValue("menuId");
```

The problem is that `query.getOutputParameterValue("menuId")` seems to ignore the `type=Short.class` annotation and returns a *Long* for some reason, which eventually throws a *ClassCastException* when I'm casting to *Short*.

Am I doing something wrong or is that a bug? I'm on Glassfish 4 with EclipseLink 2.5.0. I've also tried updating it to 2.6.4 but I get the same behavior. I tried annotating `menuId` with `type=String.class` but that is ignored as well and I still get a *Long*.

I can obviously do `myLong.shortValue()` and move on, but I'm using a couple Stored Procedures and I'd like this to work properly without hacks.

Btw, I'm not using standard *AutoIncrement* because table **Menus** has a compound PK **(venueId INT UNSIGNED, menuId TINYINT UNSIGNED)**

Thanks!

Comment: From mysql docs, "With no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value"  I would argue that your menuId is of the wrong type.

Comment: @OldProgrammer menuId data type is set according to what it is in the DB table. Our entire system (EJB 3) is mapped to reflect the correct data type in a ton of places. This is also the case in many other tables with ID columns of varying data types, that also need to use a procedure for value generation. If MySQL doesn't cast properly to the OUT param type, then the purpose of having different data types across the entire system is rendered obsolete and we'd have to use java.math.BigInteger for everything. In this case, just a primitive short is needed. MySQL only allows explicit CAST to INT